# WinAPI event at even seconds

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need to write an application, that waits for the system time, to be at even senconds.

For example I need an event at 18:00:00 and the next at 18:00:01 etc. Polling the system clock is inefficient.

Currently I am using a TimerQueueTimer, but it only allows you to wait for a duation eg 1000ms not for an exact time.

Comment: Fetch current time and let it wait for the period remaining till specific time.

Comment: For me "even seconds" is really *even* seconds, i.e. every second second. Like `18:00:00`, `18:00:02`, `18:00:04` etc. What you seem to mean is a timer that is called once *every* second?

Comment: And no matter what, you will almost always have some skewing of timers. It's detectable though, and with a little care it can be mitigated so you don't seem to skip a second (like one event happens at e.g. `18:00:09.999` and the next at `18:00:11.001`). And for most use-cases such little skewing is irrelevant and undetectable by the user, so you probably shouldn't care about it.

Comment: Either use [sleep_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until), or have a look at its implementation for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: you don't care how many intervals you skip by jitter.

```
long long time1 = 0;
long long time2;
SYSTEMTIME st;
MSG msg;
while (1) {
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    time2 = (((((long long)st.wYear) * 12 + (long long)st.wMonth) * 31 + (long long)st.wDay) * 24 + (long long)st.wHour) * 60 + (long long)st.wMinute) * 30 + (st.wSecond >> 1);
    if (time != time2) {
        /* Handle event */
        /* Will get here at the next possible CPU cycle after the clock crosses 2 seconds */
    } else {
        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, 2000 - (st.wSecond & 1) * 1000 + st.wMillisecond, QS_ALLINPUT) {
            if (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) break; /* WM_QUIT */
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
exit(msg.wParam);
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest:

```
#include <time.h>

while(true){
clock_t cl = clock();
// do your things...
cl = clock()-cl;
Sleep /* or your sleep function */ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC-cl);
}
```

It is almost 100% accurate

Comment: I don't think `clock` is the right way to go.  `clock` counts from an epoch related to when the process started, so whole seconds from `clock` may not align to whole seconds according to wall time.  Also, the standard says that `clock` counts processor time used by the process, which may be less than the actual time elapsed if the process isn't scheduled to run (though, I don't think Windows actually does that).  Finally, the units for `clock` are not necessarily milliseconds.